# How to solve this Close this "FileOutputStream"

Tags: java, sonarqube

How to solve this?

I am getting the below error : Close this "FileOutputStream". but i have closes it already in finally block

```
public void initHistoryForOldFile(File oldFile, String filePath) throws PIDException {

        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try {

            File historyFile = new File(StringUtil.append(filePath, File.separator, "history"));
            FileUtils.ensureDirectory(historyFile);

            File oldHistoryFile = new File(StringUtil.append(filePath, File.separator, "history", File.separator, oldFile.getName()));
            oldHistoryFile.createNewFile();

            if (oldFile.exists()) {
                inStream = new FileInputStream(oldFile);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(oldHistoryFile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[PIDConstants.IMAGE_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT];

                int length;
                // copy the file content in bytes
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

                }

                // delete the original file
                oldFile.delete();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occured in historyUpdateForOldFIle", e);
        } finally {
            if (null != inStream) {
                try {
                    inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception occured whole closing inStream", e);
                }
            }
            if (null != outStream) {
                try {
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception occured whole closing outStream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly? A compile-time error? A run-time error? And ... please add the complete and exact error message.

Comment: please show the full error stack..

Comment: Why are you (a) creating a new file with `File.createNewFile()` and then (b) creating *another* new file with `new FileOutputStream(...)`? Don't waste the operating system's time like this.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose : This error is coming in sonarqube.This is not compile/run time error. I am getting this warning in sonar and warning line is outStream = new FileOutputStream(oldHistoryFile); with message "Close this "FileOutputStream"."

Comment: What is your version of SonarQube and SonarJava analyzer? Try to update to the most recent version, there were some fixes in the analyzer for this kind of scenario

Answer (score 3):

If using java 7

You can use [Try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try(InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(oldFile)){}
```

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Answer (score -1):

try(InputStream instream = new fileinputstream(oldFile)){};

Comment: An exact copy of another answer is not needed